# Python: OSError: cannot load library libcairo.so.2

Tags: python, windows, cairo

I'm having some trouble running a python script on my Windows 7 platform. I've installed Python and also cairo, last one using "pip". I'm running the script using this command:

```
C:\Python34>python.exe label/make_label.py
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label/make_label.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 41, in <modul
e>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, *CAIRO_NAMES)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 34, in dlopen

    return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 118, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 411, in _make_ffi_libra
ry
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 400, in _load_backend_l
ib
    return backend.load_library(name, flags)
OSError: cannot load library libcairo.so.2: error 0x7e
```

What I've already done is the following:

- Added the PATH to GTK/bin in the environmental variable
- I check the folder GTK/bin and found "libcairo-2.dll" so I renamed it to libcairo.so

I don't know what other information could be useful in solving this but please let me know and I'll try to add it.

Comment: You have to make sure Windows (and Python) can find libcairo-2.dll. I doubt Windows/Python is automatically searching in GTK/bin. I'm not sure either that renaming the dll file to an so extension is a good thing to do.

Comment: Well, what I did was to add the location of libcairo.dll (and also libcairo.so) to the PATH of environmental variables. I've been assuming that it tries to check that location. How else can I point Python in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems cairo depends a shared library which is not in standard search library, however, the python is calling dlopen to dynamic load the library, so you could try to put the libcairo.so.2(if it's a link, then make sure the reference locates at the same folder) in the working directory. You can also try pkg-config to set the environment. see here http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html

Comment: You're indeed correct. By putting the libcairo.so file in the working directory, the script could go further. However, it started to ask for more lib-files so I ended up chucking the whole folder there, didn't have to to figure out exactly which ones were needed.

Comment: If you follow the link, and install the exe mentioned in the link with all the default options it would work.
**Note:** Make sure you close and reopen the python terminal or jupyter notebook server.

Answer (score 42):

On Mac OS X using homebrew:

```
brew install cairo
brew install pango
```

Answer (score 10):

I just fixed this on Mac OSX 10.13 with an Anaconda Python installation and `cairosvg`:

```
$ conda install cairo pango gdk-pixbuf libffi cairosvg
$ cairosvg image.svg -o image.png
```

I got the idea from https://cairosvg.org/documentation/, which says that all its dependencies can be installed with WeasyPrint. WeasyPrint's documentation for installation on MacOSX at https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#macos says to get the dependencies from HomeBrew:

```
brew install python3 cairo pango gdk-pixbuf libffi
```

So I tried it with `conda` instead and it worked fine.

Comment: Works nicely through conda. (Win10)

Comment: You saved my day bro! This answer is great and works!

Comment: You saved my day bro! This answer is great and works!

Comment: the only answer that fixes the issue on my M1 Pro!

Comment: Deserve the correct response! +1

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue (*"OSError: cannot load library libcairo.so.2: error 0x7e"*), and this is how I solved the problem on Windows (Windows 7 x64, *Python 3.4.2 x86* (MSC v.1600 32 bit)):

- **downloaded an [all-in-one bundle](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) of the GTK+** stack including 3rd-party dependencies (which contains `libcairo-2.dll` and other Cairo-related libraries)
- **extracted** this archive to a path which does NOT contain spaces <sub>(e.g. `C:\Programs\gtk+`)</sub>
- **added** the extracted directory's **`bin` subdirectory** (which contains the mentioned `libcairo-2.dll` and other necessary files) **to the PATH**

  - <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`
  - *Environment Variables...*
  - added this directory to the Path variable (either to the user variables or system variables, after a semicolon) <sub>(e.g. `...;C:\foo;C:\Programs\gtk+`)</sub>
  - OK
- `pip install cairosvg`
- tested it with a very simple code, which already had worked:

```py
import cairosvg
testsvg = '<svg height="30" width="30">\
    <text y="10">123</text>\
    </svg>'
svgConvertedToPng = cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=testsvg)
print(svgConvertedToPng)
```

Comment: the link to the all in one bundle does not work anymore

Answer (score 4):

Solved on Windows 10 as follows:

1. download the [headless UniConverter installer](https://sk1project.net/uc2/download/)
2. Find where it installed and add its *dll* subdirectory to the system path.
3. Close and re-open the command window to get the updated path.

Answer (score 2):

What I found for MAC OSX when searching the internet for a quick solution.

So after installation of the external library with homebrew:

```
brew install cairo #and other necessary stuff
```

[library linking](https://jonathansoma.com/everything/blog/2022/solution-to-no-library-called-cairo-2-was-found-error/)

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libcairo.2.dylib .
```

Need to link lib to run the python code, it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

[The 64-bit GTK3 installer](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases) worked for me. In the installer, I kept the "Set up PATH environment variable" checkbox checked, as recommended in [this otherwise outdated guide](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/cairocffi/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows).

Not important: Before that, I tried [the 32-bit GTK2 installer](https://gtk-win.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Main/Downloads) as recommended in [the cairocffi documentation under "Installing cairo on Windows"](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/cairocffi/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows), but that resulted in `cannot load library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1`, and then I found [this WeasyPrint issue](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/957) (WeasyPrint apparently uses cairo and is from the same company as cairocffi and CairoSVG), which led me to [the documentation](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows), which links to the 64-bit version linked above.