# OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found (from Custom_Widgets import ProjectMaker)

Tags: python, cmd

How to fix this error?

```
C:\Users\vanvl\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Progammeren\Project 1.02.2>python
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Custom_Widgets import ProjectMaker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\vanvl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\ProjectMaker.py", line 14, in <module>
    import cairosvg
  File "C:\Users\vanvl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\vanvl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\vanvl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "C:\Users\vanvl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is quite an annoying dependency problem because cairocffi is not built for windows, you need the additional dependency as explained there: https://doc.courtbouillon.org/cairocffi/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows

A quicker solution is to do the following:
I used pipwin which install from an unofficial repository [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo)

```
pip install pipwin

pipwin install cairocffi
```

Also see this related issue: [get cairosvg working in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265677/get-cairosvg-working-in-windows)

Comment: I started working with something els but i will check to use this on my Pyqt5. Ty

Comment: It still to confusing i started using WPF for C# to design. But thx for answering

Comment: Any idea how to resolve same issue on macOS ?

Comment: On my M1 Mac running Ventura the problem was that brew had installed libs where my cairo in $HOME could not see. The workaround was to set DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH as an environment variable. I found this explained here https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/5121

Comment: The first page you link to points to the 32-bit GTK2 installer. That didn't work for me. Instead, the 64-bit GTK3 installer worked, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77634528/5231110

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install libcairo2
```