# Why does lottie throw ImportError: cannot import name 'PngRenderer' from 'lottie.exporters.cairo'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lottie

Why does lottie give the error ImportError: cannot import name 'PngRenderer' from 'lottie.exporters.cairo'?

```
import lottie
from lottie.exporters.gif import export_gif
from lottie.parsers.tgs import parse_tgs
def convert_tgs_to_gif(tgs_file, gif_file):

    try:
        animation = parse_tgs(tgs_file)

        export_gif(animation, gif_file, skip_frames=5, dpi=48)
        return True
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("Error occurred while converting TGS to GIF.")
        return False
```

Traceback errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bubunduc\PycharmProjects\tg\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lottie.exporters.gif import export_gif
  File "C:\Users\Bubunduc\PycharmProjects\tg\venv\lib\site-packages\lottie\exporters\gif.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cairo import PngRenderer
ImportError: cannot import name 'PngRenderer' from 'lottie.exporters.cairo' (C:\Users\Bubunduc\PycharmProjects\tg\venv\lib\site-packages\lottie\exporters\cairo.py)
```

I tried to import this library in different ways, tried to understand the source code

Comment: Which version of library are you using?

Comment: @mironovmeow, 0.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is in a completely different library. [`PngRenderer`](https://gitlab.com/mattbas/python-lottie/-/blob/master/lib/lottie/exporters/cairo.py#L40) requires the `cairosvg` library. On windows, it [requires libcairo-2.dll](https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows). Therefore, **the solution to this problem is the correct installation of `cairosvg`**.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73913080/17349246) about installing `cairosvg` on windows.